# Flutter SDK got Permission deny in Parallels win10？

Tags: flutter, parallels

SDK path c:\sdk\flutter\bin

Project path C:\work\AutoDatas3\UI\auto_datas

I open the cmd with admin , an cd C:\work\AutoDatas3\UI\auto_datas

flutter run GOT:

[image]

flutter pub get:

[image]

拒绝访问：Permission Deny

Flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.21292.1000],
locale zh-CN)

[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
X Unable to locate Android SDK.
Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
(or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).
If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
`flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[!] Android Studio (not installed)

[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.

Comment: You will need the Android SDK for flutter to build android apps. First Install Android Studio and it will guide you with android SDK installation and setup.

Comment: @Khushal Jangid I'm building a windows desktop app , now i got permission problem

Answer (score 0):

Just delete .package file which created by macos